# Eclipse debug collection variable values

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, variables, expression

Is there any trick or functionality to show values of collections in values column (next to id number), (logical structures) so I don't have to extend each collection ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to go to Java->Debug-Detail Formatters.

then figure how you want it formatted and select the radio button for as the label for variables with detail formatters I think

Comment: yep, i just found it. 
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Detail Formatters

http://i.stack.imgur.com/PEFx8.png